# UTC time transformation

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to consume a web service which requires dates in UTC. So I found:

```
private static string GetDate(DateTime DateTime)
{
    DateTime UtcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime);
    return XmlConvert.ToString(UtcDateTime, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
}
```

If I do:

```
DateTime DT1 = new DateTime(2012, 3, 25);
DateTime DT2 = new DateTime(2012, 3, 26);
string s1 = GetDate(DT1);
string s2 = GetDate(DT2);
```

s1 contains:

```
2012-03-25T00:00:00Z
```

and s2 contains:

```
2012-03-25T23:00:00Z
```

Why does s2 not contain:

```
2012-03-26T00:00:00Z
```

? Thanks.

Comment: Which time zone are you in? (Note that your code would be easier to use if you'd follow normal .NET naming conventions and make the variables camelCased. It's *really* weird to see a variable called DateTime.)

Comment: Fair enough - the method was just copied. I am in (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London - is this the time change to summer time?

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, it could be worth it to have a look at DateTimeOffset (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx). Which is a DateTime wrapped with a TimeSpan (ie timezone offset).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [London time zone](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=136) had a daylight saving transition on March 25th at 1am (local time), moving from UTC+0 to UTC+1. So local midnight on March 26th in the UK was exactly 2012-03-25 23:00:00 in UTC. That's almost certainly the cause of the problem.

You should work out what you *really, really* want the values to represent. Unfortunately `DateTime` isn't very good on helping you out here in terms of clarity. You may want to *consider* using my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library - or if you don't, at least document your code in similar [concepts](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/userguide/concepts.html). (It sounds like you're trying to transform a `LocalDate` into an `Instant`, and in order to do that, you need to work out which time zone you really mean.)

It's entirely possible that you *may* be able to get away with:

```
DateTime DT1 = new DateTime(2012, 3, 25, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime DT2 = new DateTime(2012, 3, 26, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: Sure this makes sense. Silly me.